# Ошибка FormatFlagsConversionMismatchException при печати массива

Tags: java, for

Получаю ошибку

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.FormatFlagsConversionMismatchException: Conversion = s, Flags = 0
```

при печати массива

```
    //print
        for (int n = 0; n <= number; n++) {
            System.out.format("%"+(number-n)*2+"s","");
            for (int k = 0; k <= n; k++) {
                System.out.format("%4d",array[n][k]);
            }
            System.out.println();

        }
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Выглядит так, что проблема в том, что `number - n` достигает значения `0`, а в java запись `%0s` является некорректной для форматтера, что и приводит к указанной ошибке `FormatFlagsConversionMismatchException`.

Предполагаю, что вы хотели выйти раньше из цикла. Попробуйте написать `n < number` вместо `n <= number` в условии цикла for, тогда вы проитерируетесь ровно `number` раз, а не `number + 1`, так как нумерация идет с нуля.